# python selenium no element to send_keys

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, select

I just started studying selenium, so please understand if there is any mistake.
Thankyou :)

I would like to crawling a site where can create a blog called 'tistory' through selenium.

In order to create an article, you must choose one of the default mode, markdown mode, or html mode.

Basic mode is possible.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17oIT.jpg)

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_id('tinymce').send_keys("test text")
```

But I want to do is html mode, so I created a code that can automatically write through selenium in html mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peK3K.jpg)

```
text_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#html-editor-container > div.mce-edit-area > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > textarea")
text_box.send_keys("test text")
```

another element textarea

```
text_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ReactCodemirror>textarea")
text_box.send_keys("test text")
```

An error appears when I try to run it.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.74)
```

Regarding the error, I think the textarea element is an incorrect element for writing text, but I don't know what is the correct element.

this is html mode html.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9GLb.jpg)

This problem has been bothering me for three days.
Please solve this problem. I beg you.

Answer (score 0):

In **HTML mode**, you don't see an **iframe**?

or

Since in **Basic mode** you switched to an **iframe**, did you switch to `default content`?

to solve

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.74)
```

You should debug your code like below:

1. Make sure the browser is launched in full screen using

   ```
   driver.maximize_window()
   ```
2. Use `ActionChains`:

   ```
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ReactCodemirror>textarea")))).send_keys('something here').perform()
   ```
3. Use `execute_script`:

   ```
   text_area = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ReactCodemirror>textarea")))
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'write something here')", text_area)
   ```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
The reason I didn't change the iframe in html mode is because there was no iframe in html mode. 

I tried the way you answered, but I got an error :(
I have a question. Why do I have to make sure the browser is locked in full screen using?

Comment: What's the error that you've got now ? Full screen is just to make sure that elements are in Selenium view port.